# C function pointer confusion

Tags: c, function, pointers

What is the difference between these 2 declaration:

```
int operate(int (*func)(int, int), int a, int b){
    return (*func)(a, b);
}
```

and

```
int operate(int func(int, int), int a, int b){
        return func(a, b);
 }
```

These two also seems to be equivalent: `operate(sum, 1, 1)` and `operate(&sum, 1, 1)`

If I pass function `sum` as a function of 2 numbers in the place of `func`, the result are still the same. Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

§6.7.5.3/8:

> A declaration of a parameter as ‘‘function returning type’’ shall be adjusted to ‘‘pointer to function returning type’’, as in 6.3.2.1.

In other words, the two function declarations are identical.

As far as the function call goes, §6.5.2.2/3:

> A postfix expression followed by parentheses () containing a possibly empty, comma-separated
>   list of expressions is a function call. The postfix expression denotes the called function.

Since both `func(a, b);` and `(*func)(a, b)` are postfix expressions followed by parentheses, they're both function calls. Since `func` and `(*func)` both designate the same function, they both call the same function.

Answer (score 3):

The two function prototypes are equivalent.  From C99, 6.7.5.3:

> A declaration of a parameter as ‘‘function returning type’’ shall be adjusted to ‘‘pointer to function returning type’’, as in 6.3.2.1.

The two function calls (`operate(sum, 1, 1)` and `operate(&sum, 1, 1)`) are equivalent; a function decays into a function-pointer in most contexts (similar to how an array decays into a pointer to its first element).  From C99, 6.3.2.1:

> A function designator is an expression that has function type. Except when it is the
>   operand of the `sizeof` operator or the unary `&` operator, a function designator with
>   type ‘‘function returning type’’ is converted to an expression that has type ‘‘pointer to
>   function returning type’’.

Comment: The second paragraph about decay is out-of-place, I think. No decay is happening, unless you're counting `(*func)` as the function and `func` as the pointer it decays to...?

Comment: @R..: Oh I see. I was referring to `operate(sum, 1, 1)` vs. `operate(&sum, 1, 1)`.