# C++ function pointers, again. Confusion regarding syntax

Tags: c++, function-pointers

On [this page](https://www.quantstart.com/articles/Function-Objects-Functors-in-C-Part-1) I found a good example of function pointers in C++ (as well as of functors, but this question isn't about functors). Below is some copypasta from that page.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

double add(double left, double right) {
  return left + right;
}

double multiply(double left, double right) {
  return left * right;
}

double binary_op(double left, double right, double (*f)(double, double)) {
  return (*f)(left, right);
}

int main( ) {
  double a = 5.0;
  double b = 10.0;

  std::cout << "Add: " << binary_op(a, b, add) << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Multiply: " << binary_op(a, b, multiply) << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

I understand the code in general terms, but there are a couple of things that I've always found confusing. Function `binary_op()` takes a function pointer `*f`, but when it's used, for example on line 19 `binary_op(a, b, add)`, the function symbol `add` is passed in, not what one would think of as its pointer, `&add`. Now you may say that this is because the symbol `add` *is* a pointer; it's the address of the bit of code corresponding to the function `add()`. Very well, but then there still seems to be a type discrepancy here. The function `binary_op()` takes `*f`, which means `f` is a pointer to something. I pass in `add`, which itself is a pointer to code. (Right?) So then `f` is assigned the value of `add`, which makes `f` a pointer to code, which means that  `f` is a function just like `add`, which means that `f` should be called like `f(left, right)`, exactly how `add` should be called, but on line 12, it's called like `(*f)(left, right)`, which doesn't seem right to me because it would be like writing `(*add)(left, right)`, and `*add` isn't the function, it's the first character of the code that `add` points to. (Right?)

I know that replacing the original definition of `binary_op()` with the following also works.

```cpp
double binary_op(double left, double right, double f(double, double)) {
  return f(left, right);
}
```

And in fact, this makes much more sense to me, but the original syntax doesn't make sense as I explained above.

So, why is it syntactically correct to use `(*f)` instead of just `f`? If the symbol `func` is itself a pointer, then what precisely does the phrase "function pointer" or "pointer to a function" mean? As the original code currently stands, when we write `double (*f)(double, double)`, what kind of thing is `f` then? A pointer to a pointer (because `(*f)` is itself a pointer to a bit of code)? Is the symbol `add` the same sort of thing as `(*f)`, or the same sort of thing as `f`?

Now, if the answer to all of this is *"Yeah C++ syntax is weird, just memorise function pointer syntax and don't question it."*, then I'll reluctantly accept it, but I would really like a proper explanation of what I'm thinking wrong here.

I've read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33624012/function-pointer-declaration-syntax-confusion) and I think I understand that, but haven't found it helpful in addressing my confusion. I've also read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9315429/c-function-pointer-confusion), which also didn't help because it doesn't directly address my type discrepancy problem. I could keep reading the sea of information on the internet to find my answer but hey, that's what Stack Overflow is for right?

Comment: You might want to add `language-lawyer` tag, if you want chapter & verse.  This will involve implicit function pointer conversion, and function invocation of a function pointer.

Comment: Language allows implicit conversion from function name to function pointers and to make a call for function pointers. So both variants are correct.

Comment: [related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26559758/509868)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As the original code currently stands, when we write `double (*f)(double, double)`, what kind of thing is `f` then?

The type of `f` is `double (*)(double, double)` i.e. it is a pointer to a function of type `double(double,double)`.

> because `(*f)` is itself a pointer

It is not.

Q: What do you get when you indirect through a pointer (such as in `*f`)? A: You get an lvalue reference. For example, given an object pointer `int* ptr`, the type of the expression `*ptr` is `int&` i.e. lvalue reference to `int`.

The same is true for function pointers: When you indirect through a function pointer, you get an lvalue reference to the pointed function. In the case of `*f`, the type is `double (&)(double, double)` i.e. reference to function of type `double(double,double)`.

> Is the symbol `add` the same sort of thing as `(*f)`, or the same sort of thing as `f`?

The unqualified id expression `add` is the same sort of thing as `*f` i.e. it is an lvalue:

> Standard draft [expr.prim.id.unqual]
>
> ... The expression is an lvalue if the entity is a function ...

---

> the function symbol `add` is passed in, not what one would think of as its pointer, `&add`. Now you may say that this is because the symbol `add` is a pointer;

No. That's not the reason.

`add` is not a pointer. It is an lvalue. But lvalues of function type implicitly convert to a pointer (this is called decaying):

> Standard draft [conv.func]
>
> An lvalue of function type T can be converted to a prvalue of type “pointer to T”. The result is a pointer to the function.

As such, the following are semantically equivalent:

```
binary_op(a, b,  add); // implicit function-to-pointer conversion
binary_op(a, b, &add); // explicit use of addressof operator
```

---

> So, why is it syntactically correct to use `(*f)` instead of just `f`?

Turns out that calling a function lvalue has the same syntax as calling a function pointer:

> Standard draft [expr.call]
>
> A function call is a postfix expression followed by parentheses containing a possibly empty, comma-separated list of initializer-clauses which constitute the arguments to the function.
>   The postfix expression shall have function type or function pointer type.
>   For a call to a non-member function or to a static member function, the postfix expression shall either be an **lvalue that refers to a function** (in which case the function-to-pointer standard conversion ([conv.func]) is suppressed on the postfix expression), **or have function pointer type**.

These are all the same function call:

```
add(parameter_list);    // lvalue
(*f)(parameter_list);   // lvalue

(&add)(parameter_list); // pointer
f(parameter_list);      // pointer
```

---

P.S. These two declarations are equivalent:

```
double binary_op(double, double, double (*)(double, double))
double binary_op(double, double, double    (double, double))
```

This is because of the following rule, which is complementary to the implicit decay into function pointer:

> Standard draft [dcl.fct]
>
> The type of a function is determined using the following rules.
>   The type of each parameter (including function parameter packs) is determined from its own decl-specifier-seq and declarator.
>   After determining the type of each parameter, **any parameter** of type “array of T” or **of function type T is adjusted to be “pointer to T”** ...

Answer (score 3):

This is because C function pointer are special.

First of, the expression `add` will decay into a pointer. Just like reference to array will decay into a pointer, reference to function will decay into a pointer to function.

Then, the weird stuff it there:

```
return (*f)(left, right);
```

> So, why is it syntactically correct to use `(*f)` instead of just `f`?

Both are valid, you can rewrite the code like this:

```
return f(left, right);
```

This is because the dereference operator will return the reference to the function, and both a reference to a function or a function pointer are considered callable.

The funny thing is that a function reference decay so easily that it will decay back into a pointer when calling the dereference operator, allowing to dereference the function as many time as you want:

```
return (*******f)(left, right); // ah! still works
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all a function parameter specified as a function declaration is adjusted to pointer to the function when the compiler determinates the type of the parameter. So for example  following function declarations

```
void f( void h() );
void f( void ( *h )() );
```

are equivalent and declare the same one function.

Consider the following demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>

void f( void h() );
void f( void ( *h )() );

void h() { std::cout << "Hello Ray\n"; }

void f( void h() ) { h(); }

int main()
{
    f( h );
}
```

From the c++ 17 Standard (11.3.5 Functions):

> 5 The type of a function is determined using the following rules. The
>   type of each parameter (including function parameter packs) is
>   determined from its own decl-specifier-seq and declarator. After
>   determining the type of each parameter, any parameter of type “array
>   of T” or of **function type T is adjusted to be “pointer to T**”.

On the other hand, according to the C++ 17 Standard

> 9 When there is no parameter for a given argument, the argument is
>   passed in such a way that the receiving function can obtain the value
>   of the argument by invoking va_arg (21.11). [ Note: This paragraph
>   does not apply to arguments passed to a function parameter pack.
>   Function parameter packs are expanded during template instantiation
>   (17.6.3), thus each such argument has a corresponding parameter when a
>   function template specialization is actually called. — end note ] The
>   lvalue-to-rvalue (7.1), array-to-pointer (7.2), and **function-to-pointer (7.3)** 
>   standard conversions are performed on the argument expression

So what is the difference between these two declarations

```
void f( void h() );
void f( void ( *h )() );
```

For the first declaration you may consider the parameter `h` within the function body like a typedef for a function pointer.

```
typedef void ( *H )();
```

For example

```
#include <iostream>

void f( void h() );
void f( void ( *h )() );

void h() { std::cout << "Hello Ray\n"; }


typedef void ( *H )();

void f( H h ) { h(); }

int main()
{
    f( h );
}
```

According to the C++ 17 Standard (8.5.1.2 Function call)

> 1 A function call is a postfix expression followed by parentheses
>   containing a possibly empty, comma-separated list of
>   initializer-clauses which constitute the arguments to the function.
>   The postfix expression shall have **function type or function pointer
>   type**.

So you may also define the function like

```
void f( void h() ) { ( *h )(); }
```

Or even like

```
void f( void h() ) { ( ******h )(); }
```

because when the operator * is applied to a function name then the function name is implicitly convereted to pijnter to the function.